# Why am I getting Insufficient Mapping Error?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

I run code first based on a pre-existing database and I'm getting a Mapping Error.
I tried to put foreign key annotation but without success.

Here it the classes mapping:

```
[Table("tablle_1")]
public partial class Table1
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Table1()
    {
        Table2 = new HashSet<Table2>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long usu_id_apr { get; set; }

    [Other non-important columns]

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long usu_numweb { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Table2")]
public partial class usu_twebnotifi
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long usu_id_not { get; set; }

    [Other non-important columns]

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long usu_numweb { get; set; }

    [StringLength(999)]
    public string usu_obsnot { get; set; }

    public long? usu_id_apr { get; set; }

    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

And here it is the `OnModelCreation` method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Table2)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Table1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.usu_id_apr, e.usu_numweb });
```

When I the run it, I get this error:

> Data.Table1_Table2: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'my_foreign_key' in relationship 'Table1_Table2'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
>
> Table1_Table2_Source_Table1_Table2_Target: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the gist of it is that you are saying `WithOptional` and then using non nullable FK.

Comment: Should i use `WithRequired` ?